# Cannot login with SignInManager from razor component

Tags: c#, blazor

Hello i have been working with Blazor for some time, but now i had this idea to use `SignInManager<IdentityUser>` via a Razor component. But i have problem with that. I get different errors like:

`Headers are read-only, response has already started.`

`Error: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure`
The locals
[image: Not readable Locals window]

and this is my code:

```cs
@page "/test"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
                        <form id="custom__section_view-login-form">
                            <div class="register-login-form">
                                <div class="register-login-column" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                    <label>E-mail</label>
                                    <input type="email" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="register-login-form">
                                <div class="register-login-column" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                    <label>Hasło</label>
                                    <input type="password" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="register-login-form" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <div class="register-login-column text-right">
                                    <a class="reset-password-section">Zapomniałeś hasła?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="register-login-form" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                                <div class="register-login-column mt-1">
                                    <button type="submit" class="button" style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:10px; font-weight:bold;" @onclick="LoginAsync">Zaloguj się</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>

@code{

    [Inject]
    public SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager { get; set; }

    private string Email { get; set; }
    private string Password { get; set; }

    private async Task LoginAsync()
    {
        Email = "login";
        Password = "password";
        try
        {
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Email, Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Login succeeded, redirect or do something
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle login failure
                Console.WriteLine("Login failed: " + result.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ode)
        {
            // Log ObjectDisposedException
            Console.WriteLine($"ObjectDisposedException: {ode.Message}, StackTrace: {ode.StackTrace}");
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
        {
            // Log TaskCanceledException
            Console.WriteLine($"TaskCanceledException: {tce.Message}, StackTrace: {tce.StackTrace}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log generic Exception
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}, StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }

}
```

All the other files are default. Any ideas?

I tried many ways from google but nothing helped me out.

Comment: From your error screenshots, which are a pain, looks like you're having EF transient issues

Comment: please add the errors to your question instead of linking images thereof

Comment: You're injecting SignInManager into your frontend.  Firstly, this is a bad idea, and secondly, is it registered in your DI container?  Please share your Program.cs.  Frontend vs Backend aside, I recommend you have some sort of IAccountService/AccountService, which performs your Login/Register functions.  Such a service would get registered in your DI.  Checkout this example using EF Core and SignInManager -- https://github.com/CodeFontana/TodoApp  though this example uses Blazor to talk to a backend API which handles the user login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
Use the default Identity system, and search Google or YouTube for "Scaffolding identity in Blazor"

**long Answer:**
Authorization is normally sent back and forth in page requests.  For example, you log in, and the server sends the user info to the client browser.  Then in that page you click a link, and the browser sends the page request **and the auth information** back to the server.

But Blazor doesn't function this way.  It sends little packets to update the page, without any actual html request being posted.

This is why Blazor currently uses scaffolding Identity pages of the old MVC type, which DO require navigation.  Then after you log in, it sends you back to the Blazor SPA, and Blazor has access to the user info by way of HttpContext.  It's a simple solution to the problem you describe, but it is ANNOYING AS HECK.  It's probably almost everyone's least favorite thing in Blazor, I'd guess.

Comment: Someone just upvoted this.  So I need to say-- in .net 8, everything is changed.  Anyone making a new project should disregard this answer, or at least check out the changes to Blazor authentication.

Answer (score 0):

the `SignInManager<T>` likely uses the `HttpContext`. But in Blazor Server, code gets executed when the response has started, hence the error 'Headers are read-only...'. [Microsoft also discourages using it in Blazor Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#avoid-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components). Due to this, authentication is quite complicated for Blazor Server. I haven't found a good way to do it at least.

Comment: They are making improvements in .net 8, which is available in preview now, and comes out officially in November.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Ah now with support for mixed WASM and Server that might be easier indeed!